# How to rsync changes and reload remote service but only type SSH password once

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, rsync

I would like to sync local changes to a file to a remote server and then reload the service that uses that file. For example:

```
# Sync file to remote server
rsync -avzhe ssh --rsync-path "sudo rsync" \
    /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg vagrant@192.168.50.31:/etc/haproxy/

# Reload remote service
ssh vagrant@192.168.50.31 "sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy reload"
```

Doing it this way forces me to enter the SSH user's password twice. Is there any way to do this better, so that I may only have to enter the password once?

Comment: Either setup ssh key based login or look at using an automation tool, in your case ansible would suit you well.

Comment: @TimFletcher I did skim over something talking about key based login. I wonder how complex that is? I may have to look into it. Ansible is another option, but does go down a different route...

Comment: Key based login is quick and easy to setup there are lots of guides online for it.

Comment: @NickRamirez Just add `-i /path/user.key` to the `ssh` invocation and place content of `user.crt` to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote host. Key and certificate are both generated by `ssh-keygen` utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh > ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): abc.key
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in abc.key.
Your public key has been saved in abc.key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
9e:e2:46:c0:9a:ac:fe:fb:ea:ec:ee:66:00:39:91:f8 root@domain.tld
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|..               |
|+                |
| + .             |
|+ E o            |
|.o o .  S        |
| .+   .. .       |
| ..  .. o        |
|. .o ...         |
|..OX+o.          |
+-----------------+
```

Here I've omit passphrase twice by pressing `Enter`. Now I have `abc.key` and `abc.key.pub` files. Let's make them readable by me only:

```
chmod 600 abc.key*
```

Open the `abc.key.pub`:

```
ssh > cat abc.key.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDppADcp53HZ4KF7EsNcfV1qM4WtuYEeHWjAXsFqJwHd7loyKYnORHtAMtd78+cSHTiAycLeNqX9xRh/lPlhifeovxJ8th6c4W7cXNWalmz6q+RkDE8ZznmcNSvrMToLm7oivdsBDiPIBbiOtunKRQ2TsNZ72RJuC3RlrmUakWp9RcrQMFAvyxkzJYmm4fTSozosA2/NaHn0qIm/5Ed9I5BQ9IzRQLgzsXCtBTQY83aBcYLk+AzhQiM45AV1mOGzYAkgXu6Uo3P9jDxi2DE1priW8SnKEXhrTEmNDAZDkDRAz1Go/lGnENslqLZ0URs5spGtHGhcWt9DmSjVGbbGvpP user@domain.tld
```

Copy the whole line and paste it to the `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote host.

Now try:

```
ssh -i /path/abc.key user@remote.host
```

Yep, now you have been logged in without keyboard authentication at all. You can do that trick everywhere you  have used `ssh`.

Comment: This is the route I went, except that I used the `ssh-copy-id` command to copy the public certificate to the remote machine. I did not `chmod` it and wonder if you could expand on why that's important?

Comment: If key is readable for everyone `ssh` refuses to use it for authentication as non-secure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ControlMaster**, **ControlPath** and **ControlPersist** ssh options to make use of ssh connection sharing feature. Using these makes ssh keep the connection specified amount of seconds(or forever with 0) and any consequent ssh sessions will connect without requiring authentication because they will use the already established connection.

Example:

put this in .ssh/config

```
Host *
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath /tmp/ssh_shared_%h_%p_%r
    ControlPersist 60
```

this will keep the connection for 60 seconds. Durring this time you wil not be asked for password.